# Flexbox Text wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout:

```css
.main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(255, 46, 0, 0.5);
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.text2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text1">Lorem impsum pimpsum</div>
    <div class="text2">Tex2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like my text to wrap inside the `div` `.text1` and `.text2` without disturbing the `flexgrow`. In other words, is there any way to force flexbox to stay at the same size no matter the text in it?

I'm using Chrome. Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Konrad29/pen/Oxbmqx

Comment: If my answer solve the original question, please accept when possible. If your 2 _little_ question is not a followup of this, they might need to be posted as new questions, but we'll see...so give them to me

Comment: I have marked Your question as an answer. I have changed my mind about those two questions, they are unnecessary and have been answered already. Thank You for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the `flex-basis` to `0`, you control the width (distribute the space) with `flex-grow`

Update these rules

```
.text1{
  border: 1px solid red;  
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  flex:1 1 0;                      /*  updated  */
  min-width: 0;                    /*  might be needed as well  */
}
.text2{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  flex:2 2 0;                      /*  updated  */
  min-width: 0;                    /*  might be needed as well  */
}
```

This will make the `text1` to take 1/3 of the available space and the `text2` 2/3.

Based on what content you will put in each `text1/2`, you might also need to set `min-width`, which defaults to `auto`, to `0` to allow it the be smaller than its content

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLogPg)

Stack snippet

```css
.main{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color :rgba(255, 46, 0, 0.5);
}
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index:2;
  background-color: white;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content:center;
}
.text1{
  border: 1px solid red;  
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  flex:1 1 0;
}
.text2{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  flex:2 2 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text1">Lorem impsum pimpsum</div>
    <div class="text2">Tex2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```